# How do I setup large capacity SSD to be my OS and Data Backup?

Tags: partitioning, encryption, linux-distributions

I have a large capacity SSD drive that I want to utilize as follows.

**I want:**

- A Linux Distro installed to run on any (reasonably new) PC hardware.
- An exFAT partition for data storage and backup.
- exFAT data backup/partition should utilize encryption. i.e. I want my data there to be encrypted, and only I (or whoever has the password, obviously) can decrypt it, like with the OS installed on the other partition.

**More Details:**

My current setup (I planned this, then my brain froze on how to accomplish encryption on my data partition):

- I made the first partition to be exFAT for Data.
- Then I made a FAT32 ESP partition on the SSD (in case I chose to install Full Linux Distro instead of a Live CD version)
- Then I made EXT4 partition planned to be where the Linux distro would be installed.

I couldn't continue as I have no idea how to encrypt my exFAT partition.

**Hint: Will LUKS work to encrypt my exFAT partition when installing the Linux distro in the EXT4 partition?**

---

**SO FAR**

I found that a lot of results in my search suggest Gnome-Disks as an easy one stop to encrypt my partition. It seem to be the case, but the problem is that it only offers EXT4+LUKS. Now this will suffice all requirements of my needs, but I seem to not be satisfied as I want exFAT FS, not EXT4.

Can I encrypt my exFAT to be decrypted with any OS? i.e. OS-independent/cross compatible encryption scheme?

The current solution (EXT4+LUKS) actually means that I can use the OS installed on the other partition of the drive (a Linux distro that can work with EXT4) to mount and deal with the encrypted partition. So until I find a better solution, I'll be testing this setup.

Comment: It doesn't really matter what the filesystem is to LUKS. Are you trying to encrypt a partition with existing filesystem that you want to keep though? That is possible IIRC, but tricky.

Comment: Just an observation: you're paying a premium for the SSD because it offers speed.  Using it for backup seems like a waste.  Also, if what you're backing up is on the same drive, your backup is lost in any catastrophic failure, .  Or is the intention to use this as a portable drive that you plug into various computers, boot on the embedded OS, and backup files from the system?  Still, you're paying a premium for simple storage.  If you intend to use it as a portable, test boot on every candidate PC to ensure you have all of the needed drivers loaded.

Comment: Or is the intent for this to be your PC in your pocket, where you borrow any available computer to serve as your terminal?

Comment: Yes. Backup means that I need my files available on the drive, but not on the same OS partition. I don't want to lose my data in an OS failure. But I do want to make this as my personal PC using any available hardware.

Comment: Tom Yan, the drive is currently clean. No data on there yet.

Comment: Then you can just set up LUKS on the partition, and do `mkfs.exfat` on its "container" (i.e. in `/dev/mapper` or so after luksOpen). Why exfat though? If you encrypt it with LUKS you probably won't be able to open it in Windows. Why not a native filesystem that has driver in the Linux kernel?

Comment: I was thinking the same thing. I actually went ahead and choose ext4. The reason is that exFAT was the original FS by the manufacturer. And I also thought I may be able to use LUKS+exFAT on Windows and Mac with drivers that allow Windows to open LUKS encrypted volumes. But honestly that will decrease security; can't be sure of the security of an OS that's not mine. I'd stick with installed distro to decrypt my Data.

Comment: I've never heard that there's driver/utility supports LUKS on Windows myself, but well, I am not sure anyway. Hmm, usually internal SSD does not get out of factory formatted. I suppose it's a portable SSD? In any case it's probably just the industry convention originates from SDXC cards. Doesn't necessarily mean the SSD works better with exFAT.